# Jailbroken iPad stuck at boot screen and looping

Tags: ipad, jailbreak

I have a jailbroken **iPad 1** with **iOS 4.2.1**

- I replaced hosts file under /etc/ and resprang
- the iPad stuck at blank screen
- I restarted by pressing both power and home key
- Now the iPad is stucking and looping at apple logo booting screen

Currently,

- I can access the file system using iPhoneBrowser 1.9.3 and
- iTunes 10.2.1 recognizes the iPad.
- WIFI interface seems to be up but SSH is not up

Now, I have replaced the modified hosts with original file.

Still the screen never reached the lock screen.    I doubt it is file system error and in this circumstances *how can I check my iPad for file system error?* Is there a way?

#### update 1

- still stuck (have left it run out of battery)
- WiFi is not up.
- SpringBoard Crash log state that

  ```
  Reason:          Watchdog timeout: 5 crashes, 732.836304s since last successful ping   
  Thermal Level:   -1    
  Thermal Sensors: failed to load sensor values
  ```

#### update 2

- upgrade to 4.3.3
- restore with back-up data
- all are working fine now

Comment: Please post what you did to fix it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Nathan Greenstein see my udpate 2

Comment: Isn't this an obvious case of booting in DFU (Home + power, wait for reboot, wait 4 seconds, release power en hold home), and restoring via iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is to re-install the OS and then ssh in to run `fsck`.

Have you looked into a program like [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) that will let you mount iOS device as an external drive and use Disk Utility (if you have a Mac) or `fsck`? The FAQ for PhoneView has a windows software recommendation that does about the same things if you prefer that OS on the desktop.

(edit: I don't know of any free alternatives that mount the file system)

Comment: Can I know any open source or freeware alternative?? [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/faq.html) and [TouchCopy](http://www.wideanglesoftware.com/touchcopy/index.php) are both payware.